# Tengo un problema con alinear el logo con navbar

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo una pagina web para mi proyecto de Final de Curso y estoy haciendo que mi logo se centre a la izquierda con el nav , he estado intentandolo pero no llega a salir correctamente , Os paso el codigo para que me echeis un cable con esto que llevo unos dias que me esta costando un poco ya que no domino al 100% HTMl

Muchas Gracias.

```
 <nav class="menu">
      <ul>
      <img src="img/fhes.png" width="10%">  
      <li><a href="#section1">Inici</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">Qui som?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">Historia</a></li>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Serveis 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="ginecologia.html">Ginecologia</a>
      <a href="#">Consultes Externes</a>
      <a href="#">Traumatologia</a>
      <a href="#">Cirugia</a>
      <a href="#">Medicina Interna</a>
      <a href="#">Urgencies</a>
      <a href="#">Quiròfan</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
    <li><a href="#section5">Consultes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section6">Contacte</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>  

CSS
body{
    margin: 0;
}
header{
    width: 100%;
    background: #4E94AB;

}
#btn-menu{
    display: none;
}

header label{
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
header label:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para no dominar al 100% intentas atacar un problema complejo ;)

### Bloque horizontal en la parte superior de la página

Por la disposición de tu HTML supongo que quieres un menú horizontal en la parte superior de la página. A la izquierda del menú quieres mostrar el logo.

Para ello necesitas dividir el espacio horizontal en dos partes, una para el logo y otra para el menú. Lo mejor es hacerlo mediante `flexbox` puesto que así podrás controlar el espacio que ocupan y cómo se comporta en pantallas pequeñas:

```
#HTML

<header>
   <div class='logo'>
       <img src="img/fhes.png" alt="logo">
   </div>

   <nav>
     El menú
   </nav>
</header>
```

```
#CSS

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Con eso lo que logras es que el espacio de la cabecera se divida en dos partes, una para el logo y otra para el menú.

Además, `justify-content: space-between;` hace que el logo se vaya contra el margen izquierdo y el menú contra el margen derecho. Esto puedes cambiarlo si quieres otra distribución.

### El menú en sí

El menú que te propones hacer es complejo ya que no son dos o tres opciones en línea sino que hay un sub-menú.

Nuevamente, para distribuir las opciones del menú en el espacio disponible te recomiendo que para la lista (elemento `<ul>`) utilices `flexbox`.

Sin submenú, quedaría así:

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
    background: #4E94AB;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  width: 160px;
}

.logo img {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  object-position: center;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.menu ul {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://robohash.org/random" width="10%">
  </div>
  
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>  
      <li><a href="#section1">Inici</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section2">Qui som?</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section3">Història</a></li>
      <li>Serveis</li>
      <li><a href="#section5">Consultes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#section6">Contacte</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

### El sub menú

El tema del submenú es más delicado. Si quieres solucionarlo exclusivamente con HTML y CSS (sin utilizar JavaScript), entonces debes utilizar un elemento que te permita un cambio de estado **compatible con todos los dispositivos** (esto es, `:hover` no te va a servir porque en teléfonos móviles y tablets no funciona).

Es habitual utilizar en estos casos un `checkbox` y controlar según su estado lo que ocurre con el elemento que contiene las opciones del submenú:

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
    background: #4E94AB;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo {
  width: 100px; /* el espacio aquí es limitado */
}

.logo img {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  object-position: center;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.menu {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
}

input[id="dropdown"] {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

label[for="dropdown"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input[id="dropdown"] ~ .dropdown-content {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[id="dropdown"]:checked ~ .dropdown-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://robohash.org/random" width="10%">
  </div>
  
  <nav class="menu">
      <a href="#section1">Inici</a>
      <a href="#section2">Qui som?</a>
      <a href="#section3">Història</a>
      <input type="checkbox" name="serveis" id="dropdown">
      <label for="dropdown">Serveis</label>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="ginecologia.html">Ginecologia</a>
          <a href="#">Consultes Externes</a>
          <a href="#">Traumatologia</a>
          <a href="#">Cirugia</a>
          <a href="#">Medicina Interna</a>
          <a href="#">Urgencies</a>
          <a href="#">Quiròfan</a>
      </div>
      <a href="#section5">Consultes</a>
      <a href="#section6">Contacte</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Queda pendiente modificar los colores, márgenes interiores (`padding`) y exteriores de los elementos, etc., pero espero que te sea útil.